# How to getDmlFieldNames from dml exception?

Tags: apex, dmlexception

I am attempting to retrieve the field names from a dml exception.  I get values for debug statement 1 and 3.  The debug statement to retrieve dmlFieldNames doesn't have any values.  Why is this?

```
catch(System.DmlException e) {

        for(integer i = 0; i < e.getNumDML(); i++){
          system.debug('***** The items: ' + mylist[e.getDMLIndex(i)]);
          system.debug('***** The matching fields: ' + e.getDmlFieldNames(i));
          system.debug('***** The error message ' + e.getDMLMessage(i));
        }
}
```

[image: This is my debug log]

I also tried getDmlFields() but it is null.

Comment: Can you please post the whole error message? It looks like it says you're trying to create a duplicate, meaning that it's the ID field that is causing the problem.

Comment: Do you need the error message?  The problem is there is no output for the second debug statement.

Comment: I reckon that method does not take in consideration the ID field

Comment: Ah that's an interesting thought.  In the first debug statement I have a variety of fields; however, I do not have the ID field.  So that is why I cannot retrieve field names through getDmlFieldNames()?  When would it be appropriate to use getDmlFieldNames in a dml exception??

Comment: My guess is that this `getDmlFieldNames` would only report when there was something specifically wrong with a field. Required field not filled, wrong formatted email address, calling `addError` on a field, validation reporting for a field. But if you call `SObject.addError` there might not be a field to report, so perhaps is empty. This is just an "educated" guess, but I don't have time to test that theory.

Comment: Thank you both for your insight, very helpful information.  I was able to use SObject class to obtain relevant information.